# Upgrading Ubuntu chroot environment?

Tags: upgrade, apt, release-upgrade, chroot

What is the proper way to upgrade Ubuntu chroot environment to a newer Ubuntu release? The chroot environment has been originally set up using `debootstrap`.

The proper way to upgrade a Ubuntu server is to use `do-release-upgrade` command.

Ubuntu is based on Debian. Debian can be upgraded by replacing the release name in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the new release name and running `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Which one is the proper way to upgrade a Ubuntu chroot environment? What does `do-release-upgrade` do differently from the Debian way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the most part, `do-release-upgrade` is a wrapper around dist-upgrade with some additional functionality. As noted, it is the recommended official way to upgrade Ubuntu minimal/server installations. Unofficially, `dist-upgrade` after changing your `sources.list` often works just as well.

[The difference is](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html): *using do-release-upgrade is recommended because it has the ability to handle system configuration changes sometimes needed between releases.*

For an Ubuntu chroot, I suggest you stick with `do-release-upgrade` unless it keeps failing for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well `do-release-upgrade -d` works also. Just download in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

and then:

```
do-release-upgrade.
```